# randomly selected from the array or ArrayList object. The program should repeat until the user is ready to quit

Tags: java

I try to get a random line from a file.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.Random;
 import java.io.*;

 public class Magic8Ball {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
       FileReader file= new FileReader("8_ball_responses.txt");
       BufferedReader input= new BufferedReader(file);
       Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
       Random gen= new Random();
       char letter;
       String ques;
       String choice;
       System.out.println("What is your question?");
       do {
          ques= keyboard.nextLine();
          String[] answers= new String[12];
          Object lines;
          for(int i=0; i<lines.length;i++){
             answers[i]= input.readLine();
          }
          int finalAns= gen.nextInt(answers.length);
          System.out.println(answers[finalAns]);      
          System.out.println("Do you have another question? (yes or no):");
          choice= keyboard.nextLine();
          letter=choice.charAt(0);
       } while(letter!='n' && letter!='N');
    }
 }
```

8_ball_responses.txt:

```
Yes, of course!
Without a doubt, yes.
You can count on it.
For sure!
Ask me later.
I'm not sure.
I can't tell you right now.
I'll tell you after my nap.
No way!
I don't think so.
Without a doubt, no.
The answer is clearly NO.
```

I don't know, how to display this random responses

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for. Do you want the user to get a random answer from a fixed list, or should the user first enter all the potential answers?

Comment: I cleaned up the code you posted so its easier to read. Please do format your code properly before posting a question. It is so much easier to debug well formatted code, not just for you but for all people who read your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are reading the whole file every time a user asks a question, you should not be doing this. Instead read it once and keep it.

Then you use `java.util.Random` to generate you a random result. Use the [nextInt(to)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) function to get a result.

```
public class Magic8Ball {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
       FileReader file= new FileReader("8_ball_responses.txt");
       BufferedReader input= new BufferedReader(file);
       Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
       Random gen= new Random();
       char letter;
       String ques;
       String choice;
       String[] answers= new String[12]; // Reading the file only once, outside the question loop
       Object lines;
       for(int i=0; i<lines.length;i++){
          answers[i]= input.readLine();
       }
       Random random = new Random(); // get a random number generator here.
       System.out.println("What is your question?");
       do {
          ques= keyboard.nextLine();
          int finalAns= gen.nextInt(answers.length);
          System.out.println(answers[random.nextInt(12)]); // use the random number generator here where you need it.
          System.out.println("Do you have another question? (yes or no):");
          choice= keyboard.nextLine();
          letter=choice.charAt(0);
       } while(letter!='n' && letter!='N');
    }
 }
```